# Cannot understand how background-image url works in Gatsby.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I am learning Gatsby. I have a component called `Hero` which is for displaying a banner for the blog I am building.

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { Link, graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby';

const ImageBackground = styled('div')`
  background-image: url('images/plans-background.jpg'); <--- this url doesn't make sense to me
  background-position: top 20% center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-color: red; */
`;

const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <ImageBackground>
      <h1>Frontend Masster dsfsdfsd</h1>
      <p>
        hello
        <Link to="/about">learn about me</Link>
      </p>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

I'm using the screenshot to show the folder structure 
[image]

according to the structure, in order to reach the background image I need a url like this

```
`../../../static/images/plans-background.jpg`
```

And that's what the IDE prompted me to type when trying to reach the image file. However this url doesn't work as expected. There's no background image showing. and I changed it to

```
`images/plans-background.jpg`
```

The background image showed up magically.

So I don't understand why this url is working. Is it something special about the folder `static` or is Gatsby doing something behind the scene?

Also when I opened up the devtool to inspect the resources that got loaded, I didn't find this `static` file, neither the background image file.

I am really trying to understand how these pieces work together
[image]

Comment: Did you properly configure `gatsby-source-filesystem` on your `gatsby-config`?

Comment: @wentjun Hi I was following a tutorial and in the tutorial the config for `gatsby-source-filesystem` is only very bare minimal. it looks like this ` {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'posts',
        path: 'posts',
      },
    },`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gatsby: Set background image with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776791/gatsby-set-background-image-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior for your assets in `/static`, read more about it in the docs: [Using the Static Folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/).

However, adding your images there is not a best practice because they won't be optimized with Gatsby's build time image processing and `gatsby-image`.

The docs also have good resources for this: [Using Gatsby Image to Prevent Image Bloat](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-gatsby-image/), or [Working with images in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-images/).