# My website images are not loading from the correct link on Github Pages with Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, github-pages

The site is built with Gastby deployed on Github Pages.  The link to my images should be like `https://eoja82.github.io/lakeside-demo/img/employees/jake.jpg`.  However, the links are like `https://eoja82.github.io/img/employees/jake.jpg`, leaving out the /lakeside-demo part.

[image]

I'm using `pathPrefix` in my gastby-config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: "/lakeside-demo",
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `./src/components/products/data/`
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

I have the following script in my package.json file:
`"deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public"`

I've tried using Gatsby's `withPrefix` and `assetPrefix` but could not come up with any sort of working solution.

Github: https://github.com/eoja82/lakeside-demo
Website: https://eoja82.github.io/lakeside-demo/

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withPrefix` used like this should work:

```
<img className={styles.moreInfoImg} src={withPrefix("/img/loadedTruck.jpg")} alt="delivery truck" />
```

Comment: Thanks that does work!  How can I get it to work with css background images?  Is an inline style like ````<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${withPrefix('/images/image.png')})` }} />```` the best way to do it?  Saw that example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61404226/11444813