# Issue with rendering images on Gatsby site deployed to github pages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby, github-pages

I'm currently trying to help build a site for a club at my university and using gatsby to build and github pages to deploy.

The problem I'm getting is that my images aren't rendering and I think this may help figure out what's happening
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq23A.png)

The full site is: https://uoftlug.github.io

The source code is here: https://github.com/UofTLUG/UofTLUG.github.io/tree/main

For reference, I tried a solution that was proposed here: [My website images are not loading from the correct link on Github Pages with Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105506/my-website-images-are-not-loading-from-the-correct-link-on-github-pages-with-gat)

and that did in fact work this morning, but now it's sadly broken again.

Here's my current `gatsby-config.ts`

```
import type { GatsbyConfig } from "gatsby"

const config: GatsbyConfig = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `UofTLUG Club Site`,
    siteUrl: `https://www.uoftlug.github.io`,
  },
  // More easily incorporate content into your pages through automatic TypeScript type generation and better GraphQL IntelliSense.
  // If you use VSCode you can also use the GraphQL plugin
  // Learn more at: https://gatsby.dev/graphql-typegen
  graphqlTypegen: true,
  pathPrefix: "/uoftlug.github.io",
  plugins: [],
}

export default config
```

The way that I deploy this to gh-pages is through this `deploy` script in my `package.json`

```
    "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public",
```

The images are in the static folder at the root of the project.

Let me know if there's more information you need to help me.

EDIT (June 26. 2022): I probably should also note that the images render correctly when I run `gatbsy develop` and open the site in localhost

EDIT (June 27. 2022): I've found a way to fix it. What I did was use relative path instead of using the `withPrefix` function. So instead of `withPrefix("/img/tux.png")` I used `./img/tux.png`